# jquery mobile javascript calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am very new to javascript, and I am trying to build a mobile app with Jquery Mobile.  I would like the user to input one value on each page and then on the last page they will click submit and it will display the value on the last page.  I have been working on this for like 4 hours and I can get the calculation to work on the same page as the submit button but not on the next page.

```
    <script>

        function sum()
{


    var item1num = document.getElementById('item1num').value;
    var item2num = document.getElementById('item2num').value;

        {result = parseInt(item1num)*parseInt(item2num);

        document.getElementById("showResult").innerHTML = (result);}}

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="item1">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <label for="item1">
                        item1
                    </label>
                    <input name="item1num" id="item1num" placeholder="" value="" type="number" />
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <a data-role="button" data-transition="slidefade" href="#page2" data-theme="b">
                Next
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="item1">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <label for="item2">
                        item2
                    </label>
                    <input name="item2num" id="item2num" placeholder="" value="" type="number" />
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <input id="btnAdd" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="sum();" data-theme="b" />
            <span id="showResult"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page3">
        <div data-role="content">
            <span id="showResult"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code.It's displaying the result in the final page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title> 

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function sum()
    {

        var item1num = document.getElementById('item1num').value;
        var item2num = document.getElementById('item2num').value;


            {result = parseInt(item1num)*parseInt(item2num);
            document.getElementById("showResult").innerHTML = "Result is: "+(result);}
    }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="item1">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="item1">
                            item1
                        </label>
                        <input name="item1num" id="item1num" placeholder="" value="" type="number" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <a data-role="button" data-transition="slidefade" href="#page2" data-theme="b">
                    Next
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="page2">
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="item1">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="item2">
                            item2
                        </label>
                        <input name="item2num" id="item2num" placeholder="" value="" type="number" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <a href="#page3" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-transirion="slidefade" onclick="sum();">B</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="page3">
            <div data-role="content">
                <span id="showResult"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly.  I figured out my problem.  I had another page in-between the final page and my submit page.  Once I saw that the code worked, I moved my page "3" right after the submit button and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value to the pages submitting a form

```
// page1

<form action="page2" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="value1"/>
    <input type="text" name="value2"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

so in the other page you can get both and work with

```
// page2

<input type="hidden" name="value1" value="value from page 1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="value2" value="other value from page 1"/>
```

to get this with jQuery you can do

```
var val1 = jQuery('input[name=value1]');
var val2 = jQuery('input[name=value2]');
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't get this to work.  I also want it to load the automatically on the final page.